# How do I know when to upgrade RAM in Vista?

Tags: memory, windows-vista, task-manager

[image][image]

Task Manager: XP on the left, Vista on the right.

On XP, I would check to see if Peak Commit Charge was approaching Total Physical Memory.  When Peak exceeded Total during normal usage, the page file gets hit harder and performance degrades.  I would know to recommend a RAM upgrade.

As Jeff explains, [Vista uses RAM differently](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000688.html).

How do I read Task Manager in Vista to **objectively** determine if it's time to upgrade (i.e., the page file is getting taxed)?

Comment: Upgrade to Windows 7. ;)

Comment: I know my answer was tongue-in-cheek, but I'm looking forward to someone's real answer, +1 for the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend using the [Reliability and Performance Monitoring Tool](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001235.html) to see if your system is memory starved, specifically the memory section. Look for **hard faults/sec**:

> A hard fault (also known as a page fault) occurs when the page of the referenced address is no longer in physical memory and has been swapped out or is available from a backing file on disk. It is not an error. However, a high number of hard faults may explain the slow response time of an application if it must continually read data back from disk rather than from physical memory.

Comment: The problem is, this won't catch the case where system performance is heavily impacted by a lack of memory for use as a disk cache. So long as the working set of all programs fits in memory, you may not see any hard faults. Meanwhile, data pages can be thrashing badly.

Answer (score 8):

When you can afford it, buy it.  You always need more memory, especially in Vista.

Comment: 4 Gb RAM = what? 50$ I'd always max it out

Comment: yeah, it's almost cheaper to just buy the max memory your system supports than spend any time at all thinking about this.

Comment: Have to agree with Jeff, memory is dirt cheap, and you'll never regret having loads of RAM.

Comment: I disagree, it's not cheap for everyone.  I've done a lot of troubleshooting for college students and some really have to pinch pennies to afford $20 for RAM, so I have to justify it by pointing to real numbers that show it will fix their problem.  "50$ max it out" would definitely not fly.  Plus, many of them are non-technology majors and are ok w/ circumventing the issue if needs be (close 1 app to open another, reboot often, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Try using resource monitor and looking at the percentage of physical memory used.

Answer (score 1):

FYI You should be aware that there is a 4GB ram address space limit in 32bit versions of XP and vista. If you want more than 4GB, you need to use a 64bit version of windows.

For full details please refer to this [Microsoft MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778(VS.85).aspx)

So my approach has always been to install 4GB of memory in a 32bit OS by default.

Answer (score -1):

Try giving the [Crucial System Scanner](http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/) a go.

Comment: What does this application do?

Comment: crucial is a memory vendor, so I expect it'd tell you what model # of memory works in your system (ddr2, ddr3, etc)